# JSP cannot access jar from another project in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

im using Netbeans 6.9.1 and tomcat. i have Java web application and a java application. im accessing a method from jsp to my java application. the method uses a jar inside the java app. whenever i get to the line for initialization of the class in the jar, the program will go back automatically to jsp and would not return any response.